# UINavigationBar - Autowidth

Tags: uinavigationbar

Having a few issues with the auto width of a custom class I'm calling. I have it working for height, however the width continually truncates at 320px wide. I guess I could hard code each value of the screen but that's madness. I'm calling the custom class into the Global Navigation View Controller.

```
@implementation MyCustomNav

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,100);
    return newSize;
}

@end
```

I have also tried;

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width,100);
```

I get the same result with the UINavigatorBar truncating on each end. Below screen shot.

[image: Truncated UINavigationBar]

Now I did read somewhere that this is an iOS 8 bug. But I haven't confirm that yet.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it working. With iOS8 I found that it required a little different formatting but in the end this worked. The key is to set the bounds with the UIScreen mainScreen. Also use bounds it seems to work better.

```
    //Adjust the height of the NavigationBar
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,53);
    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,60)];
    return newSize;
}
```

Hope that helps someone.